# Listing categories only once

Tags: php

I'm aware this has been answered before but I have tried the solutions I have read and none work in my case. I'm listing school term dates under the category titles Term 1, Term 2, etc.
I have:

```
$PreviousTerm = '';
while (!$rs->EOF) 
{
    if ($PreviousTerm != $Term)
    {
        echo $Term;
        $PreviousTerm = $Term;
    }
$rs->MoveNext();
}
```

and am wanting to display the new category (`$Term`) if different from the previous Term, followed by its related information. 
With the above, only Term 1 is displayed followed by all of the rest of the table data.
Any help much appreciated

Comment: Use `echo "Prev Term: $PreviousTerm Term: $Term <br>;` just before the if statement and you should see where the problem is.  You should maybe give more info about the `MoveNext()` method and where `$Term` comes from - is it a string?

Comment: why `$Term` does not change in the while loop ?

Comment: Thanks @Stefan; this is showing me that PrevTerm is the same as Term in each case except the first. `$Term` is a string denoting the db field, Term 1, Term 2, etc. `rs->MoveNext();` moves us on to the next record in the table...So it seems that `$PreviousTerm = $Term;` is not working? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well after much messing, I fixed it:

```
$PreviousTerm;
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
if ($PreviousTerm < $rs->Fields['Term'])
{
echo "<tr><td><h2>Term ".$rs->Fields['Term']."</h2></td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td><b>".$Description."</b></td><td>";
echo $TermDate."</td></tr>";
$PreviousTerm = ($rs->Fields['Term'] +0.9);
$rs->MoveNext();
}
```

Seems like an odd way to have to do it, but it works! Maybe someone can explain why it didn't work in my first post?